# Difficult-to-find-license in Meta segment-anything OSS

Tags: software

I'm quite confused - like many others -  with the license that Meta adds to the **models' weights**.

The [segment-anything](https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything) repository or even the paper (I read it) do not say anything about the weights i.e:

- Are the weights for which they provide a completely open URL link also Apache 2.0 as the model is?

**Models** should be Architecture + Weights, but the wrong-use has made it ambiguous.

Also, [reading the issues](https://github.com/facebookresearch/segment-anything/issues/63) and [twitter](https://twitter.com/ylecun/status/1643684379263369216), plus that the fact that there are some companies using this commercially, seems to imply that this is the case.

But I don't like ambiguity in such a simple, well-known scenario; especially given that you need 250 GPUs to train this model in a reasonable amount of time (so we want the pre-trained weights.)

- Apart from emailing them and possibly wait forever, what do you recommend ?
- Is the Apache 2.0 linked license plus the fact that they do not say anything about the weights and provide a standard URL to download it enough to be safe legally ?

Is allowed if it is not explicitly forbidden, to assume they don't have a license (or it's Apache which is the same for most people use-case), but they aren't restricted to research ?

(A different thing is the SA-B1 Dataset, which are restricted to research purposes.)